# Extracting first 10 entries of same number in List<Class> using foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have a collection of type `NumberList`.

```
public class NumberList
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public double Profit { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }
}
```

All records are stored in **NumberList** and sorted in descending order by Number and Date.

Now i need to loop through whole list searching for Number that have 10 entries and store them in new list.

Problem i have is that i am getting 10 values but not for same number, like number 26724 have 9 entries and he take next one 18450 and add it also in list because it missing 1. Instead of adding other number it need to reset `tempList` and go on next number since it have only 9 entries.

How i can extract first 10 entries of same number and add them to new list ?

Here is code:

```
var tempList = new List<NumberList>(); // temporary list
var finalList = new List<NumberList>(); // new list where we store final results

foreach (var item in NumberList)
{
    tempList.Add(item); // add numbers to temp list

    // if temlist contains Number and number of items in list is less then 10
    if (tempList.Contains(item) && tempList.Count() < 10)
    {
        finalList.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        if (tempList.Count() == 10) // check for number of items in list
        {
            tempList.Clear(); // reset tempList
        }
    }
}
```

Example how it need to work:
Number 26724 have only 9 entries so he will not be in new list, number 18450 have 8 entries he will not be on list, number 16822 have 20 entries so we take first 10 entries of that number and put in new list.

```
26724, -6.55, 18-Jul-19 08:32:30
26724, 12.21, 20-Jun-19 03:54:56
26724, -6.53, 14-Jun-19 20:09:28
26724, 12.15, 31-May-19 17:13:25
26724, 0.98, 21-May-19 09:00:01
26724, 4.21, 15-May-19 07:02:02
26724, -6.56, 08-May-19 18:00:43
26724, -7.35, 24-Apr-19 18:40:25
26724, -6.59, 04-Apr-19 21:08:40
18450, 6.79, 18-Jul-19 22:16:26
18450, 6.69, 20-Jun-19 03:31:27
18450, 6.82, 14-Jun-19 09:57:16
18450, 6.66, 31-May-19 20:27:05
18450, -0.28, 13-May-19 15:59:08
18450, -5.95, 08-May-19 18:00:01
18450, -3.53, 24-Apr-19 12:00:42
18450, -6.05, 04-Apr-19 21:00:03
16822, 10.38, 11-Jul-19 04:56:27
16822, 9.88, 27-Jun-19 09:00:00
16822, 0.43, 17-Jun-19 16:00:02
16822, -2.36, 11-Jun-19 04:00:00
16822, -9.82, 05-Jun-19 20:08:02
16822, 13.31, 31-May-19 21:06:21
16822, 1.49, 22-May-19 10:00:02
16822, -2.8, 17-May-19 12:00:01
16822, -8.8, 13-May-19 15:07:46
16822, -8.43, 10-May-19 21:49:31
16822, -5.84, 03-May-19 16:45:26
16822, -4.91, 01-May-19 21:38:06
16822, -0.58, 01-May-19 06:00:03
16822, -1.43, 26-Apr-19 13:00:01
16822, -4.4, 25-Apr-19 10:11:29
16822, -3.58, 23-Apr-19 16:26:34
16822, -0.97, 18-Apr-19 00:01:36
16822, -2.8, 11-Apr-19 14:00:31
16822, 2.48, 05-Apr-19 13:00:15
16822, 0.2, 04-Apr-19 00:01:44
...... etc
```

So our new list should look like this from this example:

```
16822, 10.38, 11-Jul-19 04:56:27
16822, 9.88, 27-Jun-19 09:00:00
16822, 0.43, 17-Jun-19 16:00:02
16822, -2.36, 11-Jun-19 04:00:00
16822, -9.82, 05-Jun-19 20:08:02
16822, 13.31, 31-May-19 21:06:21
16822, 1.49, 22-May-19 10:00:02
16822, -2.8, 17-May-19 12:00:01
16822, -8.8, 13-May-19 15:07:46
16822, -8.43, 10-May-19 21:49:31
```

Comment: wouldl you also care for a linw solution or do you want your loop fixed?

Comment: What if there were more than one range existed over 10 times, what the output should look like ?

Comment: I am opened for any solutions.

Comment: This question needs a bit of clarification - what does `searching for Number that have 10 entries` mean. `Number` is an int, how can it have multiple entries? Do you mean entries in the list that have the Number value = 10? Also, what is the tempList?

Comment: @aelagawy there is a list of lets say 20 000 entries, in that list there is a lets say maybe 20 numbers that have 10 entries or more.

Comment: @bobbyalex number is first property in class and in output it is on first place, so numbers are 26724, 18450, 16822 .... each number can be repeated many times, so i need to count entries of each number. tempList is empty list of NumberList class where i store items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now i need to loop through whole list searching for Number that have 10 entries and store them in new list.

Foeach is not very well suited to do this job.
You need 2 For-Loops. One for each (distinct)item number and one for the comparison. Since your collection is ordered you can use this to avoid multiple iterations over the base collection. Every time when a new series starts you can remember the index end the inner loop and jump in the outer loop to the remembered location:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberList.Count; i++)
{
    tempList.Clear();
    for (int j = i+1; j < NumberList.Count; j++)
    {
        if (NumberList[i].Number == NumberList[j].Number)
        {
            tempList.Add(NumberList[i]);                
        }
        else
        {
            // Note that a new series of numbers has began and jump to this position
            i = j;
            break; // end this counting procedure
        }
    }

    // at this point evalueate the counter
    if (tempList.Count >= 10)
    {
        finalList.AddRange(tempList.Take(10));
    }       
}
```

As short Linq solution could look like this:

```
NumberList.GroupBy(x => x.Number).Where(x => x.Count() >= 10).SelectMany(x => x.Take(10));
```

Simply gather all numbers with the same value into grouped collections. 
Then apply a filter on it to check which one fit your criterion being there 10 times or more. 
Then select only those items/ungroup them and take only the first 10;

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need and that is working, good explanation.

Comment: @Mario I edited my answert and posted a full loop solution taking only 10 items. Also the linq solution is edited to take only 10 items.

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate the answer and very good explanation that will help to me understand flow of process.

Comment: @Mario you are welcome, I don't understand the downvote to your post, it has every thing a good question needs to be solved here in no time

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq to do this. For example,

```
var finalList = numberList
    .GroupBy(a => a.Number)
    .Where(a => a.Count() >= 10)
    .SelectMany(a => a.OrderBy(b => b.CloseTime).Take(10))
    .ToList();
```

So firstly we group by the number using `GroupBy`. Then, we restrict to only the groupings that contain 10 or more entries using `Where(a => a.Count() >= 10)`. Then we use `SelectMany` to flatten the groupings, and select the first 10 elements of each grouping using `Take`, with an `OrderBy` to make sure they're in a consistent order.

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
    .Where(groupings => grouping.Count() > 10) 
    .SelectMany(groupings => groupings)
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempList = new List<NumberList>(); // temporary list

var finalList = tempList.GroupBy(t => t.Number)
            .Where(t => t.Count() >= 10)
            .SelectMany(t => t.Take(10)) //take 10 elements from filtered data
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Providing code is  nice but you should also provide some explanation why and how your code works. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23590285)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a distinct on the field Number and cycle the object with the result of the distinct

```
 foreach (var item in numList.Select(x=> x.Number).Distinct())
        {
             int counter = 0;
              if(numList.Where(x=> x.Number.Equals(item)).Count() >= 10 )
              { 
                  foreach( var item2 in numList.Where(x=> x.Number.Equals(item)) ){
                      if(counter <10 ) {
                          finalList.Add(item2);
                          counter ++;
                      }
                  }
              }
        }
        foreach(var test in finalList)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", test.Number, test.Profit));
```